# legacyNamespace в statsd config для Graphite

Tags: мониторинг

Не могу до конца понять, что отключает данное поле. 
Мне необходимо указать `globalPrefix`, во всех примерах используют `globalPrefix` с `legacyNamespace: false`.

UPD
https://github.com/statsd/statsd/blob/11cfd133855b9a953a2f22bb755c7fa07527e5df/backends/graphite.js#L290 ответ на мой вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метрическое пространство имен в Graphite настраивается в отношении префиксов. По умолчанию, все статистические данные помещаются под **stats**, что упрощает консолидацию их всех в одной схеме.

Если вы решите не использовать устаревшее пространство имен(которое включено по умолчанию), помимо очевидных изменений в префиксе, также произойдет изменение способа отправки счетчиков. Когда вы отключаете устаревшее пространство (legacy namespacing) значения счетчиков с префиксамии по умолчанию находятся :

- stats.counters.counter_name.rate
- stats.counters.counter_name.count

Взято из [документации](https://github.com/statsd/statsd/tree/master/docs):

> legacyNamespace:  use the legacy namespace [default: true]
>
> globalPrefix:     global prefix to use for sending stats to graphite
> [default: "stats"]